# Neo4j remote shell connection refused on AWS database server

Tags: neo4j

My Neo4j database server is hosted in AWS.

I am using from my Mac this command:

```
$ ./bin/neo4j-shell -host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -port 1337 -name shell
```

The port 1337 is enabled in the AWS Neo4j database server.

I have these lines uncommented in the file neo4j.properties:

```
remote_shell_enabled=true
remote_shell_host=127.0.0.1
remote_shell_port=1337
```

I am getting the error:     Connection refused

Having the details:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RmiLocation.getBoundObject(RmiLocation.java:261)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:178)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:302)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:179)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:124)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 13 more
```

Don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to open quite a few ports on your server, besides 1337 and 1099 also a port range for RMI ports.

e.g. [What port is used by Java RMI connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071376/what-port-is-used-by-java-rmi-connection)

you can also use neo4j over http (e.g. in the browser with /webadmin) or via this script: https://gist.github.com/jexp/a9bf4cd3a16eb6c5997b

Comment: I am able to use http://...:7474/browser/ and http://...:7474/admin/ but I don't know which param to check to see which port RMI is using.

Comment: Also I am able connect from my dev env through a RoR app.

Comment: The script neo-http-shell.sh works when using port 7474. Not working with port 1337.

Comment: Yes, that was the intent.

Comment: However the command described in the beginning is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This key `remote_shell_host=127.0.0.1` that enables you to just connect via loopback. You have to specify by which network adapter you will receive the connection. You can also specify `0.0.0.0` for any your network interfaces.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 does not work for me. When I am using 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 the server is not starting.

Comment: I was able to make 0.0.0.0 working, I was able to restart the server. However when trying this command: ./bin/neo4j-shell -host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -port 1337 -name shell I am still getting the error message "Connection refused". I can ping successfully this IP address.