# Neo4J could not connect using Remote shell

Tags: neo4j

I could not connect to my remote neo4j instance using `neo4j-shell`.

I check if the ip/port is open to receive connection. And it is OK!

If I start neo4j-shell local, then it connects.  If I try to use it remote, `./neo4j-shell -host XXX -port 1337`, it just show me a blank line and starts waiting...

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j-shell uses Java RMI, which is difficult to use through a firewall. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071376/what-port-is-used-by-java-rmi-connection) for an explanation of why (essentially, RMI will use random ports).

Instead of using neo4j-shell remotely you can ssh into the machine running Neo4j and use neo4j-shell on that machine.