# Java RMI and netstat output

Tags: java, linux, rmi, firewall, netstat

I'm trying to make my RMI service work across a Firewall. I followed instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194948/1119716) to run both RMI Registry and my RMI service on port 1099, yet, I'm seeing different port numbers being opened on RMI client and server when I do `netstat`.

```
[user@machine] ~ $ netstat -ant | grep 1099
tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.2:33400        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.1:33378        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:33408        10.1.1.1:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.1:33408        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46866        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.2:33404        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:33378        10.1.1.1:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46862        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46864        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.2:33402        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46860        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
```

10.1.1.1 and 10.1.1.2 are both RMI servers and clients talking to each other.

This is my code snippet:

> IRemoteService stub = (IRemoteService)
>   UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(service, 1099);
>
> registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
>
> registry.rebind(IRemoteService.serviceName, stub);

Is this expected? Why am I seeing port #'s like 33400, 33378 etc? Or is my understanding of how source and destination ports work wrong? I was hoping to see all connections (registry lookup and remote service calls) going to port 1099 only.

Note: I did not run the above in a Firewall environment yet, just trying locally in my lab before I try in a Firewall situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.2:33400        ESTABLISHED
```

A connection between a client on port 33400 and a server on port 1099. You can't tell that from this line alone but you mentioned RMI which uses 1099, and there would have been a prior line with 1099 LISTENING.

```
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.1:33378        ESTABLISHED
```

A connection between a client on port 33378 and a server on port 1099. Same remark as above.

```
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:33408        10.1.1.1:1099         ESTABLISHED
```

A connection between a client on port 33408 and a server on port 1099. Same remark as above. If the client was on a different host, this line would only show at the client host.

```
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.1:33408        ESTABLISHED
```

The other side of that connection. This line only shows at the server host.

```
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46866        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.2:33404        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:33378        10.1.1.1:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46862        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46864        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:1099         10.1.1.2:33402        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 10.1.1.1:46860        10.1.1.2:1099         ESTABLISHED
```

*Et cetera.*

> Is this expected?

Yes.

> Why am I seeing port #'s like 33400, 33378 etc?

Because connections have two ends: a server end and a client end, and the client port is normally chosen fairly randomly.

> Or is my understanding of how source and destination ports work wrong? I was hoping to see all connections (registry lookup and remote service calls) going to port 1099 only.

They are. But there are client ends to those connections.

This is really a question about TCP and `netstat`, not RMI or Java.

Comment: I guess my real question is ports like `33404` (10.1.1.1:1099 `->` 10.1.1.2:33404) need to be opened on Firewall apart from 1099?

Comment: So are you saying only server ports (1099) need to be opened up on Firewall, not client ports (33408, 33404 etc.)?

Comment: I haven't said anything about firewalls, and I am totally and utterly allergic to 'so are you saying' questions, as the answer is invaraibly 'no', as it is here, but as you *now* ask it, as a *new* question, the server-side firewall must allow inbound connections on 1099 (and 10991 per your previous question); the client-side firewall must allow outbound connections to those ports; and neither firewall should make any ruling whatsoever about source ports. There is nothing to be gained by so doing.

Comment: "neither firewall should make any ruling whatsoever about source ports" - Ok, thanks for clarification. Clear now.