# Can RMI be hosted on ports above 32000?

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to RMI and I have a doubt regrading hosting the RMI server on a specific port(s).

Is it necessary that Java RMI server be hosted on ports between 1024-9000 or can it be hosted on any random port (say port 50000).

What potential problem may occur if it is hosted on such random ports (50000 or 60000) ?

I have checked [the RMI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmiTOC.html)  but couldn't find any information on hosting on specific ports.

Comment: You can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071376/what-port-is-used-by-java-rmi-connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary that Java RMI server be hosted on ports between 1024-9000

No.

> or can it be hosted on any random port (say port 50000).

Yes. From RMI's point of view there is no difference between any port number 1 to 65535.

> What potential problem may occur if it is hosted on such random ports (50000 or 60000) ?

None.

For more detail see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194948/207421).